# Why a delegate work also without defining it in the interface file?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, interface, delegates

I have a simple question to ask.

I have a ViewController that use a UITableView to show a list of things. The UITableView delegates are the this ViewController (using dataSource = self, etc..)

In all tutorials i know that i need to define the delegate class in the interface using:

```
@interface Class : SuperClass <ClassNameDelegate>
```

But all the code works good also without declaring this and implementing only the methods. For example:

```
@interface Class: SuperClass
```

Is a bug? I need to declare it anyways?

Thank you.

Mauro

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? what exactly you are trying to implement?

Comment: Be specific about the class and superclass names. Do you get any warnings (you should).

Comment: "ClassNameDelegate" is in reality a protocol. That is, methods your class should implement to conform to the protocol. Very often this is used coherent with delegates to provide additional functionality to your class. If you declare the methods without the protocol in the header, it will work most of the time since many implementations are checking if your class responds to certain selectors.

Comment: You probably are using IB to make this connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your replies. I resolved because now i got the warnings as @Wain said. I don't know why before i have got no warnings in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In common case we use `performSelector` to call delegate methods like this:

```
[(NSObject *)_delegate performSelector:@selector(storeFeedbackViewControllerWasDismissed)];
```

and everything works because this delegate have got this method.

But it's better to point that class conforms protocol because XCode can warn you to implement required delegate methods that you can miss.

Answer (score 0):

There is three moments:

1. Yours second class will return NO for call `conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ClassNameDelegate)`
2. If `ClassNameDelegate` have required methods, you will not get compilation second class error if it's not implement requited methods.
3. You will get warning if try assign object of second class to `id<ClassNameDelegate>`